# Request permission flutter IOS

Tags: ios, flutter

i am developing an app that receives notifications from firebase cloud messaging.

From the documentation I read that for IOS you need to ask for permissions from the user, the problem is that you can't bring up the banner with the request.

This is my code:

```
    void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  if (Platform.isIOS) {
    //IOS check permission
    permission();
  }
  runApp(MyApp());
}

void permission() async {
  NotificationSettings settings = await messaging.requestPermission(
    alert: true,
    announcement: false,
    badge: true,
    carPlay: false,
    criticalAlert: false,
    provisional: false,
    sound: true,
  );

  if (settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.authorized ||
      settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.provisional) {
    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance
        .setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
      alert: true, // headsup notification in IOS
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
    );
  } else {
    //close the app
    SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod('SystemNavigator.pop');
  }
}
```

Comment: Check in iPhone settings whether notifications are disabled for you app. On iPhone in this case the system notification permission won't show again.

Answer (score 0):

Create an apn key from developer.apple.com
Add this key and apn id in firebase console under cloud messaging section.
Add URL params in xcode
Add background mode capabilities in xcode and enable background, fetch and processing
Add push notification capability in xcode
Add required permissions in info.plist inside iOS/runner in your project.
Don't forget to include googleServicesinfo.plist in your runner too

https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/apple-integration
Check this link for detailed step by step process.